# Convert char to const char* String Insert C++

Tags: c++, string, insert

I have a problem with `String Insertion` because, I can not add a char, just a const char. How can i easily convert it?

The compiler just accept like this:

```
b.insert(i,"a");
```

But i want like this:

```
b.insert(i,b[ii]);
```

Full Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a,b;
    int aa=0;
    cin >> a;
    b=a;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length()+1;i++)
    {
        for(int ii=0;ii<a.length();ii++)
        {
            b.insert(i,a[ii]);
            if (b == string(b.rbegin(), b.rend()))
            {
                cout << b << endl;aa=1;
                break;
            }
            b.erase (b.begin()+i);
        }
        if(aa=1)break;
    }
    if(aa==0)
    cout << "NA" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>`? If you needed them, it should be `#include <cstdio>` and `#include <cstring>`, but I don't see that you need them at all.

Comment: I already have the answer. Thanks. stdio.h and string.h, are macros, I dont necessary need them

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert). The version that takes a single `char` also needs a count argument.

```
b.insert(i,1,b[ii]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following overload of `std::string::insert`:

```
basic_string& insert( size_type index, size_type count, CharT ch );
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert